# uninstalling the chrome using powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-ise, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to uninstall google chrome using powershell script but it shows me a popup to choose uninstall/cancel. How can i supress this by choosing uninstall button?

```
Set-Location 'path\to\my\chrome' 
.\chrome.exe -ArgumentList  '/uninstall', '/silent', '/nointeractive' -Wait
```

Comment: Have you seen this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113542/how-can-i-uninstall-an-application-using-powershell

Comment: If not, this one looks promising: `Get-Package *chrome* |% { & $_.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"] }` @George

Comment: + Get-Package *chrome* |% { & $_.Meta.Attributes["UninstallString"] }
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ("C:\path\to\...xe" --uninstall:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: What's the output of just `Get-Package *chrome*`? I saw a post suggested `\\SERVERNAME\chrome_installer.exe" --uninstall --force-uninstall` so drop the latest installer on a network path, and then run with those commands that way via UNC path... Also saw a post that says `Follow the instructions in this article: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/111899?hl=en

Get the remove.reg file, and then run it via login script in the user's session; you can remotely remove the specified folders, or add that task to the script as well.`

Comment: Get-Package *chrome* -> Here i see some output with name,version, provider name

Comment: my chrome version is 79.0.3945.130